# How to disable systemd-resolved so that netctl keeps working?

Tags: networking, archlinux, systemd

I tend to disable most `systemd` daemons, even `systemd-journald`, but `systemd-resolved` is elusive. If I disable it, netctl responds with:

```
Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
```

I believe there is a way to disable `systemd-resolved`, while keeping `netctl` functional. I disabled/masked **everything** but `systemd-resolved`, including `systemd-logind`.

```
Linux rpi4b 5.4.38-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 6 11:05:57 MDT 2020 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line in my `usb0.conf` file

`DNS=('192.168.0.1')`

So, comment all `DNS` lines out, or delete them, to make `netctl` work w/o `systemd-resolved`.

Comment: What `.conf` file do you mean?